# C# Dynamic Invoking

Tags: c#

Good Day,

I have a situation where I'm using code that contains a class called ImportFileContext.  The code looks like:

```
// One of 5 different types can be passed in
public AddImportData(CustomType ModelData)
{
    // Depending on which 5 different types, the formatted type will change
    FormattedType data = ConvertModelDataToFormattedData(ModelData);
    using (var db = new ImportFileContext())
    {
        // Can this next line be made dynamic?
        db.ImportFormattedData.Add(data);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Basically, a CustomType will always be passed in to the method.  However, there are five different custom types that can be passed in.  Depending on which 5 can be passed in, the data will be modified.

Use cases:

1. Custom Type passed in, format data to a specific format, then add that item to 
   List of the db instance.
2. Custom Type 2 passed in, format data to a specific format, then add that item to
   List of the db instance.
3. Custom Type 3 passed in, format data to a specific format, then add that item to 
   List of the db instance.

So what I'm looking for is a way add an item to the List depending on the data type without having to write several different methods to test which type I'm receiving then adding the item.  I know of the strategy pattern and I could use that, but what about adding an item to a list?

I'm really trying to avoid writing code that would look like:

```
// One of 5 different types can be passed in
public AddImportData(CustomType ModelData)
{
    // Depending on which 5 different types, the formatted type will change
    FormattedType data = ConvertModelDataToFormattedData(ModelData);
    using (var db = new ImportFileContext())
    {
        if (typeof(ModelData) == "CustomType")
            db.ImportFormattedData.Add(data);
        elseif (typeof(ModelData) == "CustomType1")
            db.ImportCsvData.Add(data);
        elseif (typeof(ModelData) == "CustomType2")
            db.ImportTabDelimetedData.Add(data);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

TIA,

coson

Comment: Can you edit ImportFileContext? And, are the ImportFormattedData, ImportCsvData, etc ... essentially static properties of the ImportFileContext object?

Comment: How would you like your code to look like? What do ImportXxxData methods exactly do? Do all your ModelData objects belong to a class with a common base class? Can they implement interfaces? Your question it's too obscure. Please, give more explainations, specially about ImportXxxData methods implementation. If we don't know what does that method do, it's impossible to help you. If we know, we could use your strategy, reflection, interfaces, base classes...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how feasible this is for your application, but you can always add the specific behavior to the CustomType class and subclasses can implement it however they need to.

```
public class CustomType
{
    public virtual void FormatAndWriteToDB(DataBase db);
}
```

And then sublasses override as needed

```
public class CustomType1 : CustomType
{
    public override void FormatAndWriteToDB(DataBase db)
    {
        FormattedType data = ConvertModelDataToFormattedData(ModelData);
        db.ImportCsvData.Add(data);
    }
}
```

That would make your code very clean in the example method:

```
public AddImportData(CustomType ModelData)
{
    ModelData.FormatAndWriteToDB(db);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Of course you can change this around a bit. For example, if the FormattedType call is common to all of them, you could leave that in the AddImportData method and pass it as an argument to the FormatAndWriteToDB method.

The advantage of this is future additions just require implementing the new subclass of CustomType and no modification is needed to AddImportData.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're looking for double-dispatch.  You can do this with the Visitor Pattern--which is basically what David Mason detailed--where you decouple the algorithm from the data by putting logic (the visit) into the class that contains the data.  That, of course works, but requires you to modify the class outside of the algorithm in order to visit.

I find this complex and it's really just there because statically typed object oriented languages don't normally do runtime overloading.  Fortunately in C# 4 they introduced the `dynamic` keyword which allows use to implement double dispatch much easier--or at least in a way that looks more like method overloading.  Which means you create the method overloads, assign the value to dynamic variable, then invoke the method.  The method that gets call will be chosen at runtime based on the value.  For example:

```
public static void AddImportData(CustomType ModelData)
{
    FormattedType data = ConvertModelDataToFormattedData(ModelData);
    using (var db = new ImportFileContext())
    {
        dynamic temp = ModelData;
        ImportData(ModelData, data, db);
    }
}

private static void ImportData(CustomType modelData, FormattedType data, ImportFileContext db)
{
    db.ImportFormattedData.Add(data);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

private static void ImportData(CustomType1 modelData, FormattedType data, ImportFileContext db)
{
    db.ImportCsvData.Add(data);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
private static void ImportData(CustomType1 modelData, FormattedType data, ImportFileContext db)
{
    db.ImportTabDelimetedData.Add(data);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have more details on my blog at: [http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2010/05/24/using-the-dynamic-keyword-in-c-to-improve-object-orientation.aspx](http://bit.ly/ghLVqk)